# can't set a div inside a div perfectly?

Tags: html, css

Here is My [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mdu7a/)

My wrapper div is not rendering inside my second div.

I am trying to place a div inside a second div, but wrapper div is created above the second div.

I couldn't find the bug. So can anyone help fix this?

```
body {
margin:0px;
}

.homebar
{
height:40px;
background-color:#242c3c;
display:block;

}
#nicebody
{
display:block;
min-width:960px;
}

#wrapperdiv
{

border:3px solid green;
height:28px;
width:163px;

}
```

my home.aspx

```
<body id="nicebody" class="goodstyle" data-twttr-rendered="true">
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div class="homebar"></div>
  <div id="logo" style="left:225.5px;">
      &nbsp;<a class="home">SGIPC</a></div>
    <div id="nav" style="top:45px; left: 0px;">

      <div id="seconddiv">

          <div id="wrapperdiv"></div>

      </div>

</form>
</body>
```

Comment: Suggest to make a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Also, try to narrow down your code so it will show only the specific problem. This is just too long

Answer (score 0):

It actually *is* rendering inside `div#seconddiv` --> I gave it position: relative; and top: 200px; or so…

Check it: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sL3UC/)

You just need to position it, but I would suggest using margin and not position + top.

Comment: "using margin and not position +top" i couldn't understand it clearly..plz explain...

Comment: Look at the JSFiddle example I provided. See the green-bordered rectangle? That's your div. I made it visible by moving it down the page with `position: relative` and `top: 104px` – two new CSS rules I set. These rules though could easily be swapped out for `margin-top: 104px` which would most likely do the same thing, and be a little cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

I think to put css Float:left; for both div #seconddiv and #wrapperdiv

lky below

CSS:

```
#seconddiv { float:left; }

#wrapperdiv{
   float:left;
   border:3px solid green;
   height:28px;
   width:163px;
}
```

Comment: float:left is not working ..i want the green bordered div in the right of second div..but it is showing above the seconddiv..
check:[http://jsfiddle.net/KS7xw/]

Comment: if u put float:left for both element'na, surely wrapperdiv come inside of seconddiv dude.. http://jsfiddle.net/mdu7a/1/

Comment: i used position:relative and top:200px it worked for me..but float:left is not working..why??i can't figure it out..

Comment: if your are using postition:relative; or absolute... then float:left; won't work